# Prove that forcing A is superior to offering opponent a choice between A and B

Tags: game-theory

In a game of *Magic* earlier today my opponent played [Coercive Portal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382231), which led to a situation in which he could either:

- force me to choose *A*; or
- allow me to choose *A* or *B*.

I was surprised when my opponent let me choose *A* or *B*. This struck me as a mistake as it guaranteed me my preferred outcome (assuming correct play):

```
| choice | my preferred outcome | actual outcome | optimal for me |
| ------ | -------------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| A      | A                    | A              | yes            |
| A      | B                    | A              | no             |
| A or B | A                    | A              | yes            |
| A or B | B                    | B              | yes            |
```

How does one express this situation in game theory? Is my reasoning sound? If so, what is the formal proof?

Comment: I think the trouble here arises from the fact neither player necessarily has perfect information. Given that I'm not sure there is a formal proof. I'd be interested to read others comments.

Comment: Given the information available to me, I could determine whether _A_ or _B_ was preferable for me from my perspective. My opponent may have offered me a choice because he had access to information hidden from me which led him to *want* me to choose _B_, and he hoped I would determine _B_ to be preferable and so choose it. A trap. There's a foolproof counterstrategy to this ploy: I could choose _A_ every time regardless of which option I think better for me. Were I to fall into a trap after choosing *not* to employ a foolproof counterstrategy, can I claim to have played correctly? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

In the situation described, forcing a choice of A [dominates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_dominance) allowing either a choice of A or B.  That is, the outcome for the opponent is always at least as good if he or she makes the dominating choice.

However, there are some  conditions:
1. If there are more than 2 players, there may be good reason to not beat up on someone.  #2 might want #3 to stay alive so that together they go after #1.
2. The best play in life might not always be the best play in a game.  Perhaps the opponent was trying to be nice.
3. There are no other differences between the two moves for the opponent.  This is hard to evaluate not knowing any other details apart from coercive portal.

Comment: 1) It was a two-player game in this case. 2) My opponent is a friend, but we both like to win. 3) I was assuming that the outcome which is preferable for me must be worse for my opponent and vice versa. Is this always the case in non-cooperative two-player games?

Comment: 3) It is not always the case.  Suppose we play a simple game where we repeatedly flip a coin -- heads you get a dollar, tails I get a dollar -- until one of us is bankrupt.  I also have a special button I can press if I like, that gives you 3 dollars and me 300 dollars.  If I press this button, it is good for you, but even better for me.

Comment: I chose the word "preferable" carefully because we're not necessarily comparing one good option and one bad one: we could be comparing two good options or two bad ones. Is there a more precise word I could have used instead? In the coin-flipping game my odds of winning diminish each time you press the button. I therefore prefer that you do not press it, which implies that you prefer to press it.